# Reaching definitions involving pointers

Tags: c, compiler-construction, analysis

Suppose I have a piece of code:

```
int x = 100;
int* p = &x;
*p = 20;
print(x);    //<= reaching defitition of x?
```

It will output 20 upon execution.
The problem is which statement is the reaching definition of `print(x)`, the initial assignment or the pointer assignment?

Also in the following code:

```
void sub(int* p)
{
    *p = 20;
}

int x = 100;
sub(&x);
print(x);    //<= reaching defitition of x?
```

the same problem exists. Is it a special case of reaching definitions analysis, or require special algorithm to process it?

Comment: What do you mean by "reaching the definition"?

Comment: It the reaching definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaching_definition

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand more how pointers work
Imagine that you have 1 tv and 2 remote controls
In the first example, variable x(remote control) has a value (100) and address (TV). Now comes a pointer *p that points to the same address as x (second remote control to the same TV). 
When you change the value (TV channel) of *p, you expect the value of x to be changed accordingly. So now both *p and x holds the value 20(same TV channel), and same address (2 remotes for the same TV)

I hope its a bit more clear now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood reaching definition correctly, but here goes:

In your first sample, `*p = 20` is your reaching definition because it assigns the value `20` to `x`.

In your second sample, again `*p = 20` in `sub()` is your reaching definition because it assigns the value `20` to `x`.

`p` contains the address of `x` and `*p =` modifies the value stored at address that `p` holds.